# Lead Management System Comments Show for Assigned User

Tags: php, crm

I am currently still learning PHP and I have been working on this project for a little over a week. I am pulling my hair out. So, we have a Lead Management System, users can enter comments for leads assigned to them. We want those comments to be hidden if the the lead is discarded or assigned to another user.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php $lead_id = $row['id'];?>
    <?php $getcommentscount_stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_by_user_id = $_SESSION[user_id] AND lead_id = $lead_id ORDER BY comment_created_on DESC";?>
    <?php $result_commentscount = mysqli_query($mysqli, $getcommentscount_stmt);?>
    <?php $comment_count = mysqli_fetch_row($result_commentscount);?>
    <?php $num_comments = $comment_count[0];?>



    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Comments<span class="caret"></span> <span class="badge pull-right"><?php echo $num_comments;?></span></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
<div id="collapseTwo<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <tr>
        <td width="25%"><strong>Time</strong></td>
        <td width="75%"><strong>Comment</strong></td>
        </tr>
     <?php $lead_id = $row['id'];?>
        <?php $getcomments_stmt = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_by_user_id = $_SESSION[user_id] AND lead_id = $lead_id ORDER BY comment_created_on DESC";?>
        <?php $result_comments = mysqli_query($mysqli, $getcomments_stmt);?>
        <?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_comments)) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td width="25%"><?php echo $row2['comment_created_on'];?></td>
        <td width="75%"><?php echo nl2br($row2['comment_text']);?></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php } ?> 
    </table>
```

This is the last thing I tried:

```
<?php $getcomments_stmt = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_by_user_id = $_SESSION[user_id] AND lead_id = $lead_id AND times_assigned <> 1 OR times_assigned IS NULL ORDER BY comment_created_on DESC";?>
```

I am not sure what else to show, but any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am getting this

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/html/showleads.html on line 884
```

Line 884:

```
<?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_comments)) { ?>
```

Comment: What's the actual question? Are you getting an error? Is the data not showing correctly?

Comment: I edited the question, thank you.

Comment: ok, at a guess, I would say that `mysqli_query` is failing and returning `false` hence the error.  Can you debug `$getcomments_stmt` and run it on a database to see what it returns?

Comment: It looks like it's the bit `times_assigned <> 1 OR times_assigned IS NULL`

I am not sure what else I could do.